# How to get a addon to my datepicker that's centered

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to get my datepicker to be centered and I have not stumbled upon any problems while using Firefox. Was going to try with Chrome and IE and the `input-group-addon`-`glyphicon` wont get centered along with my datepicker. Does anyone know a way to solve this, or point out what I've done wrong in my thinking?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0k60y710/2/

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="step2" class="stepDiv" style="text-align:center">
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <div class="input-group"> 
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" style="height:30px;" class="datepicker1" placeholder="Select a date" value="" name="date1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container-xs-height {
    display:table;
    border-spacing:5px;
}
.row-xs-height {
    display:table-row;
}
.col-xs-height {
    display:table-cell;
    float:none;
}
.col-xs-middle {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to work against the framework here. Not entirely sure what your custom classes are for. Try using the built in [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) with [offsets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) in order to centre your content. The good thing about using the grid system is you can be specific about how it looks on different size screens as well. I've edited your code to use the Grid system instead.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="step2" class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" style="height:30px;" class="datepicker1 form-control" placeholder="Select a date" value="" name="date1" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0k60y710/3/)

Heres a summary of what I did and why.

- Added a 'container' div around your code. the grid system will not work properly without it.
- Added the grid classes into your 'step' div. On 'xs' size screens it will take up 10 columns with a 1 column offset (making it centred), on 'sm' it will take up 8 columns with a 2 column offset, and on 'md' screens it will take up 6 columns with a 3 column offset.
- I added a class of 'form-control' to your datepicker to make it render like a Bootstrap form field
- Cleaned up the HTML a bit

Comment: Not how I solved it, but it got me on the right track! I had forgotten to add a div with the right proportions! Thank you!